# How to copy a part of a line to another position

Tags: sed, awk

I have about 100 print statements in a file like this:

```
printf("%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
```

I want to copy the variable name inside the string  so that it becomes like this

```
printf("row1.req_pnttime: %f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
```

Can anyone help me do this?

PS-The length of the variable name is different for every print statement so I need a generic way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(.*("\)\(.*,\)\(.*\))/\1\3: \2\3)/' /path/to/input.txt >/path/to/output.txt
```

### Explanation

- The general format is `sed 's/find/replace/'`. i.e. find an expression and replace it.
- `\(` ... `\)` these are capturing groups. So anything that matches in between them is "captured" in a variable and can be recalled in the replace part, with `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, etc.
- So here, find `\(.*("\)\(.*,\)\(.*\))`.

  - Capturing group 1: `.*("`. Capture from the beginning to anything that ends with `("`
  - Capturing group 2: `.*,`. From #1, capture up to `,`.
  - Capturing group 3: `.*`. Capture up to (but not including) `)`.
- Then replace with the capturing groups and additional formatting `\1\3: \2\3)`.